# Spring Restful Web Service Using Maven

Tags: spring, web-services, maven, restful-url

I need a guide for making a restful spring web service using maven(not mandatory).
Please don't share any link which is server dependent.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As Barney would say: Haaave you met Google?

Comment: Yes and I've fulfilled my requirement myself... :)